# Is it possible to convince a Java application to ignore SSL issues without modifying its code?

Tags: java, ssl

I have some java apps that are complaining about different SSL problems like self signed certificate or not trusted ones.

As I do not have the code of these apps and getting good certificates is too hard, I am looking for a solution that would allow me to force it to connect.

So far I tried these but it seems not to be enough:

```
-Dcom.sun.net.ssl.checkRevocation=false 
-Djava.security.debug=certpath
```

I still see:

- `sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target`
- `javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target`

Comment: Have you tried setting a keystore, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5871279/java-ssl-and-cert-keystore

Comment: That's the other approach which doesn't seem to always work.

Answer (score 7):

Code modifications to ignore certificate validation errors by ignoring trust verification altogether (e.g. using a trust manager that does nothing) are normally not the right way to go. They may be popular with some developers, because they don't have to go through any steps about dealing with certificates, but they're just ignoring the problem instead of fixing it, thereby also introducing vulnerabilities to MITM attacks. (Because the problem is then silenced, it tends never to be fixed in production releases.)

The various ways to configure trust management are described in the [JSSE Reference Guide](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/security/jsse/JSSERefGuide.html#Customization).

In short, you can either import the certificates explicitly into the JRE truststore (usually `cacerts` file in the JRE directory) or by using importing it into your own trust store (possibly based on a copy of the default trust store), and specifying its path using the `javax.net.ssl.trustStore` (and related) system properties (see JSSE Ref Guide).

These configuration settings will affect all the `SSLSocket`s and `SSLEngine`s that use the default settings themselves (without any specific `SSLContext` in the code).

Some applications use their own `SSLContext` to load a specific keystore or truststore for certain connections. This is usually configured with parameters that are independent of the JSSE default options, in which case you'll have to check the application documentation or code.

Answer (score 6):

https://web.archive.org/web/20160316150251/http://code.google.com/p/misc-utils/wiki/JavaHttpsUrl provides several invasive solutions.

SSLSocketFactory can be [overridden with system property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6078492/how-to-create-custom-sslsocketfactory).

But [custom HostnameVerifier](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6031258/java-ssl-how-to-disable-hostname-verification/13032654#13032654) can be endorsed with just a special Java agent via an additional startup parameter or [on the fly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4817670/how-can-i-add-a-javaagent-to-a-jvm-without-stopping-the-jvm/13032771#13032771).

Furthermore, [AspectJ weaving agent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6811579/how-to-create-a-jvmti-agent-to-see-all-the-loaded-classes-objects-and-their-fie) can be used to [override any method behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8273685/is-it-possible-to-override-a-method-at-runtime).

Also consider alternative approach with [MiTM HTTPS proxy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8129260/man-in-the-middle-mitm-proxy-with-https-support/) (if application allows reconfiguring urls and certificates).

Answer (score -2):

Yes it is possible.

Using JVM args :

```
-Dcom.sun.net.ssl.checkRevocation=false
```

Or programarically:

You can override the default TrustManager and HostnameVerifier .
This link give [reusable code example](https://tutoref.com/how-to-disable-ssl-certificat-validation-in-java/).